# linq to sql: how to create key in in orm?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a view that is a composition form several sources (for read only), so none of the keys are unique.  Can I create a key to use in Linq-to-sql, or should I just create an composite column in my view that is a concatenation of all the keys.

Comment: I have just created a concatinated key in the view... that works, just wondering if there was a way to do it in the orm

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to, if you don't want to. Linq to SQL only requires primary keys when you want to update or insert data, and I guess you don't want to in a view.

You can use a simple where statement with all your keys in it to select rows:

```
from item in dc.SomeView
where item.Key1 = 500 && item.Key2 == "abc" && item.Key3 == 16
select item
```

Comment: Ahh, yes it is because I am using a Domain Service that is causing my issues.  It requires that you have a primary key defined

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to create a concatenated key in the view..

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko: he is the author!